# Вывод .txt файлов

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Есть, к примеру, 2 файла .txt. Мне нужно вывести их подряд, а не построчно. Как мне это сделать?
Пытался через for, выводит только 1 .txt.

Comment: `for %x in (*.txt) do @type %x` или там `forfiles /M *.txt /c "cmd /c type @file"`...

Comment: Если файлов именно два, напишите просто без циклов: `@echo off
type file1.txt
type file2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не совсем понятен, если вам нужно увидеть все файлы, то

`dir /b "./*.txt"`

выведет в все файлы с расширением txt по одному в строке в консоль. Или то же с сохранением в файл:

`dir /b "./*.txt" > mylog.txt`

Если нужна переменная со списком файлов, то в bat-файле делаем такую запись:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set __my_list=
for /f %a in ('dir /b "./*.txt"') do set "__my_list=!__my_list!;%a"

echo !__my_list!
```

а если этот список нужен после `endlocal`, то добавить

`endlocal & set "MY_TXT_LIST_GLOBAL_VAR=%__my_list%"`